# Why is my Angular KeyValueDiffer previous value null?

Tags: angular

Background - I have another component that deep clones the data and changes it before emitting that so in order to keep the reference the same for the key value differ I have created a deep clone on this component, at least for now.

For some reason the first time getChangedNewRoles is called all my roles are returned. After that it works properly. I have gone out of my way to ensure references are not changing so this now makes no sense to me..

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const data = ... get my data
    const cloned = deepClone(data);
    this.setupKeyValueDiffers(cloned);
}

getChangedNewRoles(newData: Role[]): Role[] {
    const changedRoles: Role[] = [];

    for (const differ of this.roleDiffers) {
        const existingRoleId = differ[0];
        const existingRoleDiffer = differ[1];

        const matchingNewDataRole = newData.find(x => x.id === existingRoleId);
        const matchingOriginalDataRole = this.cloned.find(x => x.id === existingRoleId);

        // key value differ only works properly if the objects being compared have the same reference
        // but we dont want to change AllRoles before saving so we store a deep clone internally here as well
        Object.assign(matchingOriginalDataRole, matchingNewDataRole);

        const changes = existingRoleDiffer.diff(matchingOriginalDataRole);
        if (changes) {
            changedRoles.push(matchingNewDataRole);
        }
    }

    return changedRoles;
}


private setupKeyValueDiffers(data: Role[]): [string, KeyValueDiffer<string, any>][] {
    const differs: [string, KeyValueDiffer<string, any>][] = [];

    for (const role of data) {
        const differ = this.keyValueDiffers.find(role).create();
        differs.push([role.id, differ]);
    }

    return differs;
}
```

EDIT:

I noticed that the internal records property of existingRoleDiffer in getChangedNewRoles was empty so I changed setupKeyValueDiffers to this:

```
private setupKeyValueDiffers(data: Role[]): [string, KeyValueDiffer<any, any>][] {
    const differs: [string, KeyValueDiffer<any, any>][] = [];

    for (const role of data) {
        const differ = this.keyValueDiffers.find(role).create();
        differ.diff(role as any);
        differs.push([role.id, differ]);
    }

    return differs;
}
```

I am calling diff inside here and that has populated the records property properly. Now my code works...

Edit all the properties are null on the differ when I first create it without calling .diff at the end. That surely makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.keyValueDiffers.find(role)
```

Only checks the type of the argument is something you can apply a differ to. Thats why its needs an initial diff call.